# Coin Tossing Game Optimal Stragegy

Tags: probability, algorithmic-game-theory, infinite-games

A and B are playing coin toss game with a fair coin as a team, both of them have to be correct in a game to be able to gain one point, no communications will be allowed after the game starts.

Assuming A has some super power and knows all of the results ***after the game starts, to be more specific, A knows what the current toss will be and what the next result will be***. However, B is just an ordinary person.

Assuming they are going to play this game forever, is that possible A and B could come up with a strategy before the game starts so that the possibility of their correct guess is greater than 0.5 in the long run?

Comment: To clarify, at any given point in time, A only knows the upcoming result, not results from further future coin tosses, correct?

Comment: A having access to future outcomes but only after the game starts gets around the possibility of recording the information and still allows the possibility of a successful game strategy without direct communication.

Comment: @Cardinal I think your assumption makes sense... otherwise the 100% correct will make this problem meaningless

Comment: @Cardinal I have made the assumption clear in the original question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes A knows *all* of the results after the game starts, or more specifically, A knows what the current toss will be and what the next result will be.

B will select heads (arbitrary) on the first toss and then follow the rule established before the start of the game.

Rule: If B incorrectly guesses the current toss, then B will guess on the next toss whatever A guessed on the current toss.

A and B will use a predetermined strategy to capitalize on A’s ability. An obvious pattern would be for B to guess the same outcome as the previous toss unless directed differently by A from the Rule.

Example 1:

Toss 1 will be heads.
A knows B will select heads and they both guess correctly.

Toss 2 will be tails, but A also can see toss three will be tails. A knows B will incorrectly guess heads, so A signals Toss 3 will be tails by guessing tails via the Rule.

Toss 3 will be tails.
A knows B will select tails because of Rule from Toss 2 and they both guess correctly.

Example 2:

Toss 1 will be heads.
A knows B will select heads and they both guess correctly.

Toss 2 will be tails, but A also can see toss three will be heads. A knows B will incorrectly guess heads, so A is signaling Toss 3 by guessing heads via the Rule.

Toss 3 will be heads. A knows B will select heads because of Rule from Toss 2 and they both guess correctly.

Notice how in these examples, the team cannot possible miss two tosses in a row.

If my thinking is correct...

The subset for two tosses changes from {CC, IC, CI, II} of equal distribution to {CC, CI, IC}, where C denotes correct and I denotes incorrect.

All of the II become IC so the distribution is CC=0.25, CI=0.25, IC=0.5 for very large numbers of games.

CC x 0.25 outputs 0.5C
CI x 0.25 outputs 0.25 C and 0.25 I
IC x 0.5 outputs 0.5 I and 0.5 C

Total ratio is 1.25:0.75 or 5:3 Correct to Incorrect. vs 1:1 by a no strategy method.

Conclusion: long run success = 0.625

Comment: just one question - how (Incorrect Incorrect) is possible considering A will always know the result...

Comment: Incorrect Incorrect here represents the result of two tosses, not the guess of each participant. Also, using this strategy, I-I is not a possible outcome because A can use the rule to indirectly signal to B. Under this strategy, if A is ever guessing wrong, it is intentional to signal to B what the next toss will be.

Comment: Thanks! now I am clear